# Installing Apache Struts2 on OS X

Tags: macos, apache, jsp, struts2

I have decided to have a look at JSP technology and some of the frameworks surrounding JSP. However, I am struggling to find information regarding the installation of the JSP API, the servlet API and how to configure them all to run through Apache on OS X.

If anybody could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 as well as JSP api, are platform independent, so doesn't matter if you using OS X  or other OS.

Maybe the easiest way to get a Struts2 application (including servlet and jsp apis) working is [installing maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) and then execute the command line text provided from [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart).

AppFuse's maven project will provided you with Jetty, and the JSP api will be marked as a provided dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
 <version>${jsp.version}</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding these two dependencies will be provided by the container you will be using as they are part of specification.

For using Struts2 all you need to place the required dependencies in your class path (lib folder of your project) and when you will deploy the application those above dependencies will be fulfilled by the container.